# Helpful error messages in jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am implementing a RESTful Webapp in Jersey on the Grizzly 2 server and I have the following class.

```
@Path("/FaultTree")
public class FaultTreeResource  {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sendGetJson(@QueryParam("treeid") String treeid) {
     return "You requested fault tree number "+treeid;
  }
```

}

If I go to http://localhost:8080/FaultTree I get the message "Request failed", because I forgot the query parameter. Now this behavior makes sense in production. However, during development I would like a more helpful error message. How can I enable helpful error messages or at least logging in Jersey?

The sendGetJson-method isn't executed (according to Eclipse debugger), so logging it there is not an option.

Comment: Two things I always do during development is 1. Register the Jersey `LoggingFilter` 2. Register an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` that prints the stack trace. Sometimes errors occur that are never logged because there is no handler. The mapper handles the logging in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to enable logging in Grizzly I add the following code just above where I call startServer():

```
 Logger l = Logger.getLogger("org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler");
 l.setLevel(Level.FINE);
 l.setUseParentHandlers(false);
 ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
 ch.setLevel(Level.ALL);
 l.addHandler(ch);
```